# Why does it add an extra "and" here?

Tags: conjunctions

This is a sentence from my dictionary:

> She carried herself straight and with confidence.

The sentence is fairly strange to me, for the extra conjunction "and". Normally I would say something like this:

> She carried herself straight with confidence.

This is more regular to me. For example, I would say "*She stood here, smiling with confident.*" But I wouldn't say "*She stood here, smiling and with confident.*" So why did the original sentence add an extra "and"?

Comment: Note that *and* is a conjunction, not a preposition.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> She carried herself straight and with confidence.

Including *and* tells us that both *straight* and *with confidence* describe *carried*. The sentence means this:

> She carried herself straight. Also, she carried herself with confidence.

If you leave out *and*, then *with confidence* describes *straight*.

> She carried herself straight with confidence.

This means that she was straight because she was confident.

For example:

> She stood there, smiling with confidence.

*With confidence* is how she *smiled*, not how she *stood*. In this sentence, she expressed her confidence through her smile.

> I wouldn't say "She stood here, smiling and with confidence."

I would probably construct this sentence a little differently, but it's perfectly sensible. Here, she expressed her confidence with the way she stood. Also, she was smiling at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I think the non-parallel construction calls attention to itself and makes the sentence a little more interesting. I also like the rhythm.

It could have been written with a comma to make it clearer what the prepositional phrase is modifying.

> She carried herself straight, with confidence.